# TestFlight APK error parsing application name

Tags: android, testflight

I'm receiving this error while I want to upload apk file on testFlight

```
'Invalid APK: Failed to parse application name from AndroidManifest.xml.'
```

This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example._APP_NAMEreceiver.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example._APP_NAMEreceiver.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.ReceiverMenuScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.ShowMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.Prefs"
            android:label="@string/smsinbox_title" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY" />

        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.SMSReader"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_smsreader"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.SMSSender"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="MY_PACKAGE._APP_NAME.SwitchMode"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have two folders 'values-pl' and 'values-en' with strings named"app_name", value=APP NAME.

I tried to rename app, delete testflight.lib etc. Did anyone has this problem? Or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a default folder "values" where you put your default values (potentially english resources).